# sql get SET values from form checkbox

Tags: php, sql, forms, checkbox

I'm working on an SQL database and would like to know how to get the values of multiple checkboxes and update a SET in the database using PHP? I need to be able to select one or more values and update the set.

For example:

SQL

```
UPDATE options 
SET option1='$_POST[option1]', option2='$_POST[option2]', option3='$_POST[option3]',
WHERE... ";
```

PHP

```
echo "<input type=checkbox name=option1 value=" " /> ";
echo "<input type=checkbox name=option2 value=" " /> ";
echo "<input type=checkbox name=option2 value=" " /> ";
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Haven't actually written this part yet..just trying to figure out how to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$options = $_GET['option'];

foreach ($options as $option){
    echo $option
}
```

Comment: the user is using `POST` method

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE options 
SET option1='$_POST[option][0]', option2='$_POST[option][1]', option3='$_POST[option][2]',
WHERE... ";

echo '<input type=checkbox name="option[]" value=" " />';
echo '<input type=checkbox name="option[]" value=" " /> ';
echo '<input type=checkbox name="option[]" value=" " /> ';
```

Comment: @mhasan your code will fail if only two checkbox is  checked. you need to check the posted value before inserting into databse

Answer (score 0):

You can get Selected Checkbox value like this,

```
echo '<input type=checkbox name="option[]" value="1" />';
echo '<input type=checkbox name="option[]" value="2" /> ';
echo '<input type=checkbox name="option[]" value="3" /> ';
```

Then You can get that values & set it in a serialize format to insert in database like this,

```
$values = $_POST['option'];
$values = serialize($values);
```

Here You can insert `$values` in database field. In a same way, while updating you can fetch field value & unserialize it. Then compare it to the original value. if it is in the array then you can `checked` it.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$i=0;
while($i<3)
{
if(!isset($_POST['option'][$i]))
{
$_POST['option'][$i]="";
}
$i++;
}
UPDATE options SET option1='$_POST[option][0]', option2='$_POST[option][1]', option3='$_POST[option][2]',
WHERE... ";


echo '<input type=checkbox name="option[0]" value=" " />';
echo '<input type=checkbox name="option[1]" value=" " /> ';
echo '<input type=checkbox name="option[2]" value=" " /> ';
```

Comment: @user3464091 can you please tell me how you implemented this ?